# How do you download only the modules or pages of a wikibook and their images with wget?

Tags: wget

With the instructions found on internet, wget over the modules of a wikibook recursively downloads everything. How can I download only modules and images contained in the modules ??

Comment: How do you define *module*? Please add also `wget` command which you have tried to use

Comment: This is the index of a wikibook on Pascal with the related modules or pages of the book: https://it.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=Template%3APascal&action=edit and this is the wget instruction that download everything and not just the modules: `wget --limit-rate=200k --no-clobber --no-parent --convert-links --random-wait -r -p -E -e robots=off -U mozilla https://it.wikibooks.org/wiki/Pascal`